# Exclude .bak files from build

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

How can I exclude certain files and folders from build and other tasks like creating a war file, copying files ?

I would like certain files like '.bak' to be excluded from build

Is there an equivalent of ant defaultexcludes task ?

I know that I can use ant.defaultexcludes in gradle but I was looking for an alternative

Comment: Would you mind sharing your build.gradle?

Comment: Its a 1000 lines long.
Ok.
I think I got it.
Should I explicitly mention in the code to exclude them in every copy task ??

Comment: Is it possible to make a File collection of "those" files and exclude them from every copy task ?

Comment: You can configure all `Copy`, `Zip` and similar tasks at once with something like `tasks.withType(AbstractCopyTask) { it.exclude '**/*.bak' }` or if you have a multi-project build `allprojects { tasks.withType(AbstractCopyTask) { it.exclude '**/*.bak' } }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure all `Copy`, `Zip` and similar tasks at once with something like `tasks.withType(AbstractCopyTask) { it.exclude '**/*.bak' }` or if you have a multi-project build `allprojects { tasks.withType(AbstractCopyTask) { it.exclude '**/*.bak' } }`.

Comment: This is good.

I have a task which has multiple copy closures. Those copy tasks are not excluding the .bak files . I can surely divide them into multiple tasks of Copy type. Or is there a way to configure those too ? Can I configure all copy tasks(copy closures in some task) ?

Comment: Nope, Copy closures are like method calls, Tasks like Objects. You can only configure the objects.